# Can't create symbole file for module because port has unsupported type

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, quartus

I am having this weird problem where Quartus won't generate the symbole file for the following code:

```
module bin_to_bcd #(parameter N_DIGITS = 4) (count, bcd_output);

input wire [$clog2(9999)-1:0] count;
output reg [(N_DIGITS<<2)-1:0] bcd_output;

integer i;
integer decade;

always @ (count) begin
    bcd_output = 'b0;
    for(i = $clog2(9999) - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1) begin
        for(decade = 1; decade < N_DIGITS + 1; decade = decade + 1) begin
            if(bcd_output[(decade<<2) - 1 -: 4] >= 5) begin
                bcd_output[(decade<<2) - 1 -: 4] = bcd_output[(decade<<2) - 1 -: 4] + 3;
            end
        end

        bcd_output = bcd_output << 1;
        bcd_output[0] = count[i];
    end
end

endmodule
```

The error that is thrown is :

```
10016 Can't create symbol/include/instantiation/component file for module "bin_to_bcd" because port "count" has an unsupported type
```

But "count" is an "input wire" as it should be and I have other similar code that work just fine.
Maybe I'm missing something obvious but I would greatly appreciate any help I can get.

I should also mention that this code works perfectly fine in simulation in ModelSim-Altera.

Thanks.

EDIT: I would also like to be able to specify a number of digit for the output as a parameter if anyone as any idea how to implement this. 
Note: $clog2({N_DIGITS{9}}) does not work...

EDIT #2 : I'm sorry if I am responding slowly I was working on something else. So the problem still presents itslef and I haven't figure out why... Here is some insight that might be useful. The following code works perfectly fine and uses the same type of register sizing with $clog2. If someone sees any differences between the code I posted and this one, please step forward and shout "I FOUND IT!", because this is driving me crazy :P

```
module multiplexer #(parameter N_INPUTS = 2, parameter N_OUTPUTS = 1) (in, out, select);

generate
    if (N_INPUTS % N_OUTPUTS != 0) begin
        illegal_parameter_cant_divide_inputs_by_outputs non_existing_module();
    end
endgenerate

input wire [N_INPUTS-1:0] in;
input wire [$clog2(N_INPUTS/N_OUTPUTS) - 1:0] select; //THIS LINE WORKS FINE
output wire [N_OUTPUTS-1:0] out;

assign out = in[(select + 1) * N_OUTPUTS - 1 -: N_OUTPUTS];

endmodule
```

Edit #3 : I actually just noticed that the multiplexer code did not get synthesized properly as a symbol (the select port is missing... I applied the same fix and it's OK now).

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: my guess is that quartus has issues with '$clog2'. try to use just a number, like `[12:0]`

Comment: I use $clog2 for size bracket in other code and they work fine. But i tried and it works now??? Can someone tell me why this code doesn't work and some of my other code which uses the same exact syntax for the count statement work?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the syntax. So, it could be a tool bug. Try the latest version. Try to simplify code one by one to find a work-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Verilog-2005 and SystemVerilog syntax, I cannot spot anything wrong with your code. It ran fine on [EDAplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/) with various simulators. If `bin_to_bcd` is in a `.v` file and `multiplexer` has a `.sv` file, then it could be it could be how the file is being parsed. `$clog2` is not a build-in type for Verilog-2001, you you might want to make sure Verilog files are being parsed as 2005 and not 2001. Though I recommend using the SystemVerilog `.sv` file type.

As for makking `$clog2(9999)` scale based on `N_DIGITS`, use `$clog2(10**N_DIGITS-1)`.

You might also want to assign `$clog2(...)` to a parameter. ANSI header style example:

```
module bin_to_bcd #(
  parameter N_DIGITS = 4,
  parameter IN_BITS = $clog2(10**N_DIGITS-1)
) (
  input wire [IN_BITS-1:0] count,
  output reg [(N_DIGITS<<2)-1:0] bcd_output );
```

Comment: I didn't even think of searching for a power notation...thx a lot :P And I'll try everything you just said and come back with some more info :)

Comment: Doing it the ANSI header style did the trick, don't know why though... My file were already .sv and Quartus was set to compile Verilog file as SystemVerilog anyway.

Comment: It's not the ANSI-style header, it's using a parameter for the bus width definition as per my answer below.

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm getting confused by the words used here which I never heard "ANSI header" (I thought it meant declaring parameter a certain way). But could you explain why this works...it seems hacky...

Comment: @ZacharieMcCormick  as an experiment, try changing `input wire` to `input` with your non-ANSI header. It is legal to specify the net_type on an input since Verilog-2001. However it was illegal in Verilog-1995. If it works with that change then you found a bug in Quartus. Regardless, I prefer ANSI style whenever possible. I only use non-ANSI for obscure corner cases or tool limitations.

Comment: It doesn't work when I do that (these are not the bugs you are looking for :P)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve your error by setting the `$clog2` expression to a parameter, then using the parameter to bound the bus.

```
module test #(
    parameter N_DIGITS = 4,
    parameter int M = $clog2(9999) // see here
)(
    count, 
    bcd_output
);

input wire [M-1:0] count; // and here
output reg [(N_DIGITS<<2)-1:0] bcd_output;

integer i;
integer decade;

always @ (count) begin
    bcd_output = 'b0;
    for(i = $clog2(9999) - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1) begin
        for(decade = 1; decade < N_DIGITS + 1; decade = decade + 1) begin
            if(bcd_output[(decade<<2) - 1 -: 4] >= 5) begin
                bcd_output[(decade<<2) - 1 -: 4] = bcd_output[(decade<<2) - 1 -: 4] + 3;
            end
        end

        bcd_output = bcd_output << 1;
        bcd_output[0] = count[i];
    end
end

endmodule
```

> #### `Can't create symbol/include/instantiation/component file for module "<name>" because port "<name>" has an unsupported type (ID: 10016)`
>
> **CAUSE:**
>
> You attempted to create a symbol/include/instantiation/component file for the specified module in a Verilog Design File (.vhd). However, the specified port on the module has a type that cannot be represented by a symbol/include/instantiation/component file. Unsupported port types include SystemVerilog structs, interfaces, or modports. Most array or vector types are generally supported, but the their **bounds must be defined by constant expressions or by simple arithmetic expressions involving module parameters and integer literals**. Because the specified port has an unsupported type, the Quartus II software cannot create a symbol/include/instantiation/component file for the module.
>
> **ACTION:**
>
> Omit the port from the module declaration or change its type.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/13.0/mergedProjects/msgs/msgs/evrfx_symbol_cant_handle_verilog_port.htm

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what the standard says, but good practice is to always use ANSI style ports, particularly in conjuction with ANSI style parameters.

This would look like:

```
module bin_to_bcd #(parameter N_DIGITS = 4) (input wire [$clog2(9999)-1:0] count, output reg [(N_DIGITS<<2)-1:0] bcd_output);
```

Comment: OP's declaration is absolutely normal, according to the standard.